# How to decode URL in classic asp if the url is pass throuh encodeURI in javascript?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have a url that is encoded in javascript using encodeURI function:

javascript code:

```
encodeURI("form.asp?opt=" + ai_opt + "&val=" + escape(ls_val) + "&col=" + as_col + "&sg=" + ls_sg + "&oldval=" + escape(ls_old_val)
```

Sample Output:

```
/form.asp?opt=1&val=Field%2520Fisher%2520Waterhouse%2520%2528London%2529&col=loc
```

How to decode the query string values in server side using classic asp?

I should able to extract correct values from query strings:

```
opt = 1
val = Field Fisher Waterhouse (London) 
col = loc
```

Comment: If you natively read the query string value, it should already be decoded. For example: Request.QueryString("val")

Comment: Meaning, I should directly read from Request.QueryString and no need to worry eventhough it is encodeURI in javascript?

Answer (score 5):

If you natively read the query string value, it should already be decoded.

For example: `Request.QueryString("val")`.